# Cant scroll with ListView.builder()

Tags: flutter

I was wondering if anyone had an issue where they use a ListView.builder() and then it doesn't want to scroll

```
                   return ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                       
                        itemCount: widget.product.category.length,
                       
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final item = widget.product.category[index];

                          return ListTile(title: Text(item));
                        },
                      )
```

Comment: How long is your list? Try setting `shrinkWrap` to false.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do the following:

1. Remove shrinkWrap and make sure the value passed to itemCount is large enough to make the widget scroll.
2. If you place the list view inside a vertically scrolling list, it's not going to scroll... In this case, you should probably be using slivers